# How does the OS know which assembly language it needs to translate itself to?

Tags: c, compilation, operating-system, cpu-architecture

It is said that most of the OS is written in a portable computer language (usually C). This is done so that the OS can function on different CPU architectures. Naturally, the part of the OS that is not written in C (or some other high level language) will contain some compiler that will translate the OS C code into machine language. If that was the case, how does the [compiler within the] OS knows which machine language to translate the C code into?

Comment: The operating system does not remain as C up till execution. Instead it's compiled ahead of time for a particular architecture. There isn't (in general) a compiler included in an operating system.

Comment: The OS doesn't compile itself every time it boots.  A human chooses to build an x86-64 kernel using an x86-64 C compiler and so on, then boots that on an x86-64 machine.  The entire kernel binary image is x86-64 machine code (and data).  That's why you have to download / install the right version of an OS for your computer, same as other pre-compiled software.  e.g. https://wiki.debian.org/SupportedArchitectures has links to the different architectures they support as a whole distro.

Comment: @PeterCordes But how can the same kernel binary image work in different computer architectures?

Comment: It doesn't, that's exactly my point (and Thomas's).  If you want to boot Linux on an AArch64, you need to have downloaded / installed an AArch64 kernel image, or built one from source using an AArch64 C compiler, and build options that will get the Makefile to assemble the arm64 assembly, not the x86-64 assembly.  Different binaries **can** be build from the source tree, it doesn't happen on the fly.

Comment: What makes a kernel special is that some of the source files need to only be built for certain architectures, because they contain arch-specific code.  I think you're misinterpreting this as saying you get a portable binary like with Java.

Comment: To add on this, if you look at the Linux source code, you'll find an `arch` folder which contains all the specific details needed for a specific processor architecture, as well as specific assembly code. The reset is architecture agnostic because it is built upon the arch-specific section.

Comment: @Peter If I understood you correctly, the parts of the OS that are written in C can be compiled [using different compilers] to different machine languages. Does that mean that the parts that are not written in C (and thus in a machine-specific language) need to be rewritten for each C compilation?

Comment: Re-*written*?  No, you don't have to open up a text editor and create new arch-specific `.S` files after every build.  They don't get deleted every time you run `make`; that would make it really inconvenient to maintain those parts of an OS...

Comment: @Peter No, I mean the OS developers write most of the OS in some high level language (like C) and some of the OS in a machine specific language (assembly). If they wanted to deploy their product on a praticular CPU architecture, they can compile the C part of their OS to the machine language of that architecture, but would they also need to re-write the part that they built using assembly? (given that the targeted architecture is different than the one they initially wrote the non-C code to)

Comment: To a new CPU architecture, one that there wasn't source code for in the kernel tree? Yeah, of course, you'd have to write those parts for the new ISA, including some hand-written asm, and some C to manage data-structures unique to that ISA, like the hardware page-table format.  I'd assumed before we were talking about a kernel source tree that already had arch-specific parts for multiple different architectures, like Linux for example: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/arch, such as ARM64 syscall entry points: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/arm64/kernel/entry.S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OS you install is written in machine code for your particular class of computer. The developers at Microsoft (for example) already compiled the OS into x86 machine code so x86 computers could run it. They put the x86 machine code on the CD and that was installed onto your computer.

The compiler knows to make x86 machine code because Microsoft told it to. Perhaps Microsoft also made a ARM64 or SPARC version of their OS - but that's not the one you bought. If you did buy it, it wouldn't work on your computer and you'd have to return it.